# Semantic UI Css image alignement

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

i have a problem... i can't center my logo (logo_tool.png) image, it stays on the left. why? please help

```
<div class="pusher">
    <div id="top-menu" class="ui inverted <?php echo $general['layout_theme']; ?> labeled icon menu">
        <a class="item" ng-click="toggleSidebar()">
            <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
            <?php if(isset($main_menu['top_menu_button'])) echo $main_menu['top_menu_button']; ?>
        </a>
        <a href=""><img class="ui medium centered image" src="/images/logo_tool.png""></a>

        <?php if($donation['enabled'] && $donation['top_menu_show']) : ?>
            <div class="right menu">
                <a class="item" ng-click="openDonationModal()">
                    <i class="bitcoin icon"></i>
                    <?php echo $donation['top_menu_button']; ?>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Never use local src paths of images when posting on SO. Try with: #top-menu {text-align: center}

Comment: Also, don't show PHP code (or server-side code in general), when you want to discuss a purely client-side problem. No one here has your server-side setup available, to quickly get your code to work - so please provide the resulting HTML code instead. [mcve]

Comment: I'm not too familiar with semantic-ui but it looks like the issue is that the `.centered` class uses `margin:auto` to center the image, but that will only work inside a full-width block element, not in an inline one (the `<a>`) as you have it.  Try centering the `<a>` itself, or make it a block container for the image.

Comment: Could you can make the question more reliable and put pure HTML/CSS code? PHP is irrelevant for the case of CSS/HTML question. Also, if it's too complicated for you, you could start by creating a static webpage and style it as you want, then turn it to dynamic with PHP or whatever.

Comment: @DanielBeck it worked!
`<div id='ui center aligned container' style='width:100%;overflow-x:scroll;'><a href=""><img style="height: 60px;" src="/images/logo_tool.png"></a></div>`